# Passing qsub variables to .pbs script which calls python

Tags: python, bash, qsub

I'm using qsub with the -v flag like so:

`qsub -v START=0,COUNT=30000 foobar.pbs`

This passes START and COUNT just fine to foobar.pbs BUT foobar.pbs eventually needs to call something like this:

`python /home/CS4/bin/myrun.py foo_bar.ini`

The problem is it appears is that bash is not interpreting the python call properly and the python process is never spawned.  This must be something very simple?  Any help would be appreciated

pbs script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#PBS -N test
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=1:mem=4gb
#PBS -l walltime=2:00:00
#PBS -j oe

set -x 
cd ${PBS_O_WORKDIR}
export PYTHONPATH=/home/CS4:${PYTHONPATH}

TEMPL=/home/CS4/in/tr/1km/foo_bar.ini.m4
DIR=$(dirname ${TEMPL})
BASE=$(basename ${TEMPL} .m4)
INI=$(basename ${BASE} .ini).${START}.ini
m4 -D START=${START} -D COUNT=${COUNT} ${TEMPL} > ${DIR}/${INI}

time python /home/CS4/bin/myrun.py ${DIR}/${INI}
```

Comment: Is output visible to you when the script runs?

Comment: @konsolebox everything below `set - x` is printed in output with a `+` before it -- echoing those commands. The m4 macro is creating the .ini file for python execution. This part works great.  Only python does not get executed.

Comment: 1. Does python call work without use of `time`? 2. Also, try `-V` option to export the shell environment, which typically includes path to python. 3. Are there any errors reported by SGE i.e. from `qstat -j <jobid>`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try providing full path to python?

Comment: I updated the OP with the export PATHPATH declaration.  It was in the original PBS script but I did not put it in the code block.

Comment: Um, PYTHONPATH is for where python finds its modules. I'm talking about full path to python executable. e.g. /usr/local/bin/python or something like that.